# Show that a matrix is not positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

> Given fat matrices $X$ and $Y$ with full row rank, and diagonal matrix $D$, show that $X^t D Y + Y^t D X$ is never positive definite.

I can see that $X ^t D Y + Y^t D X$ is of the form $A + A^t$. But I am not sure how to proceed. I also know that it suffices to show that there is a negative eigenvalue of this matrix, but can't see how to do that

Comment: Sorry. It is given that the number of rows of X and Y are less than their number of columns.

Comment: Try showing that a square matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A + A^{T}$ is positive definite. Then I think that it'd be good to argue that there exists $\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$ such that $\vec{x}^{T}X^{t}DY\vec{x} = 0$.

Comment: What is a fat matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Dan's hints . . .

Let $B$ be an $n{\times}n$ matrix.

Then for any $n{\times}1$ column matrix $x$, we have
\begin{align*}
x^T(B+B^T)x
&=x^TBx+x^TB^Tx\\[4pt]
&=x^TBx+(x^TBx)^T\\[4pt]
&=x^TBx+x^TBx\qquad\text{[since $x^TBx$ is a $1{\times}1$ matrix]}\\[4pt]
&=2(x^TBx)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that $B+B^T$ is positive definite if and only if $B$ is positive definite.

Let $m,n$ be positive integers, with $m < n$.

Suppose $X,Y$ are $m{\times}n$ matrices, and $D$ is an $m{\times}m$ symmetric matrix ($D$ need not be diagonal; symmetric will suffice).

Since $Y^TDX = (X^TDY)^T$, to prove $X^TDY+Y^TDX$ is not positive definite, it suffices to prove $X^TDY$ is not positive definite.

Since $m < n$, there exists a nonzero $n{\times}1$ column matrix $v$ such that $Yv=0$.

But then $v^T(X^TDY)v=0$, so $X^TDY$ is not positive definite.

It follows that $X^TDY+Y^TDX$ is not positive definite.